# fetch values of a variable from a function

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I'm trying to pass data into my function and if there's no data being pass it will just use the default value instead.

---

```
<a id="process" onclick='process(,"testing","test value")' href="#">Process</a>
```

---

```
function process(passvar1,passvar2,passvar3) {


  var defvar1 = 'default value 1', 
      defvar2 = 'default value 2', 
      defvar3 = 'default value 3';



  if (typeof(passvar1)=="undefined") {
      passvar1 = defvar1;
      return passvar1;
  }


 if (typeof(passvar2)=="undefined") {
      passvar2 = defvar2;
      return passvar2;
  }


  if (typeof(passvar1)=="undefined") {
      passvar1 = defvar1;
      return passvar3;
  }


  alert ('retuern values here ' + passvar1 + ' ' + passvar2 + ' ' + passvar3);
```

Code play : http://jsbin.com/oledeg/

Comment: not sure, why I can't return the values and not sure if it's this the best and optimize how to do it. I feel I used too many 'If's...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your comment, you can simply the function like this:

```
function process(passvar1, passvar2, passvar3) {
   passvar1 = passvar1 || 'default value 1';
   passvar2 = passvar2 || 'default value 2';
   passvar3 = passvar3 || 'default value 3';

   return 'retuern values here ' + passvar1 + ' ' + passvar2 + ' ' + passvar3;
}

alert(process("testing","test value", "third value"));
// retuern values here testing test value third value
```

In your function, since you `return` in each if condition, only first condition is executed and function is returned with just one variable.

Comment: Thanks Sarfraz. Yes Anthony pointed the 'return' issue to me and that's what i'v been missing.

Thanks for optimizing my code.. this is definitely what i'm looking for. I'll be borrowing it :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
onclick='process(,"testing","test value")'
```

That's a syntax error. Make it

```
onclick='process(undefined,"testing","test value")'
```

Comment: I tried putting 'undefined' to it, but I can't seem to return the values. I'm not sure what I missed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error in your `onclick` attribute aside, you're calling `return` in each of your `if` statements - if any of those evaluates to true you're going to prematurely return from the function, and never reach the `alert` statement. Simply remove those lines since they don't do anything beneficial.

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing that out. that's what i keep missing out. Fix my issue. I'll just try to see if this is optimized.

Answer (score 0):

look at

### Process

at process(, var, var)

is this what you intended?

Comment: the first value is supposed to be an undefined value.

Comment: k, asking. sorry for weird syntax. Dont know how that happened